# Is Ethereum Virtual Machine suitable to run a blockchain in it?

Tags: go-ethereum

Is it wise (or is it recommended?) to create a blockchain inside Ethereum's Virtual Machine? Or would it be a waste of resources? I mean, what are the capabilities of Ethereum to run a blockchain inside it? And how big it could be? Would it be very costly. Because to create my own blockchain I can get Ethereum's sources , learn Go, and after some time create my own blockchain from it. But I also can create blockhchain with smart contract, but how limited would it be? This is what my question is about.

Comment: It would be helpful if you can describe what your goal is. Storing large amounts of data in smart contracts costs a lot of transaction fees.

Comment: A blockchain inside a blockchain? A meta-blockchain? Like, a blockchain run through a series of smart contracts, inside another blockchain? :-)

Comment: inception starring the cypherpunks

Comment: @RichardHorrocks, yes, like running a Bitcoin blockchain inside Ethereum. But not for a currency, but for real estate, or identity records... I don't know, there can be many applications that can use blockchain technology